# Find components which have intersections with designated lines

Tags: image-processing

I have an image with several disconnected components, and I want to find all the components which have intersections with some designated lines which I generated previously.
The image:
[image]

And the line is

`{{{37.7754, 1001.}, {38.862, 0.}}, {{0., 442.679}, {832., 437.26}}}`

The combined image looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `DeleteSmallComponents` (try 10, then 100, or more) would take care of it here, since the bigger components are connected anyway.

Comment: If you can polygonalize the image components then it should be straightforward to test for line-intersect-polygon (I think those are called "stabbing queries", but the kind that do not involve police investigations).

Comment: How do the coordinates of the line correspond to the pixels?

Comment: @BoLe Yeah that works! I ended up using ImageMultiple to obtain the desired image with no lines. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In most cases the shape is irregular, so the polygonalization may be quite slow?

Comment: @rm-rf I use Show[img,Graphics[{White, Thick, Line /@ coordinate_list}] to combine them

Comment: Another possibility, if the image is just two colors, is to make line and white section have values of 1/2, black values of 0, superpose, and grab components that now have a value of 1. The XXXDetect functions could be of use here.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the labels for the individual components using `MophologicalComponents` and simply multiply by the binarized line plot to get the labels of the components that intersect:

```
im = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq6JZ.png";
pts = {{{37.7754, 1001.}, {38.862, 0.}}, {{0., 442.679}, {832., 437.26}}};
line = Binarize@Graphics[{White, Line /@ pts}, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> (ImageDimensions@im)];

labels = MorphologicalComponents[im];
intersect = Rest@Union@Flatten[labels ImageData@line]
(* {4, 5} *)
```

You can plot only the intersecting components and overlay the lines with:

```
blobs = Colorize[labels, ColorRules -> (Map[# -> ColorData[31]@# &, intersect] ~Join~ {_ -> Black})];
ImageAdd[blobs, line]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also,

The standard setup:

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq6JZ.png"];
pts = {{{37.7754, 1001.}, {38.862, 0.}}, {{0., 442.679}, {832., 37.26}}}; 
line = Binarize@Graphics[{White, Line /@ pts}, Background -> Black, 
                                                          ImageSize -> (ImageDimensions@im)];
```

and then just:

```
Rest@Union@Flatten@Pick[MorphologicalComponents@im, ImageData@line, 1]

(*{4, 5}*)
```

Comment: Again, short and sweet. That gets my vote.

Answer (score 2):

This borrows heavily from @rm -rf at least for the start. Also it is not as clean. It might still be of interest in terms of determining and selecting specific image components.

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq6JZ.png"];
pts = {{{37.7754, 1001.}, {38.862, 0.}}, {{0., 442.679}, {832., 
    437.26}}}; line = 
 Binarize@Graphics[{White, Line /@ pts}, Background -> Black, 
   ImageSize -> (ImageDimensions@im)];
```

Now remove filled in areas of the components.

```
im2 = EdgeDetect[im];
```

Next create an averaged image of this and the lines (I'm sure there is a Cleaner way to do this part).

```
im2 = EdgeDetect[im];
data = ImageData[im2];
ldata = ImageData[line];
datasum = (data + ldata)/2;
totalImage = Image[datasum];
```

The point is that we now have large values exactly at the crossings of those lines with image components. We can extract those as below.

```
mb = MorphologicalBinarize[totalImage, {.9, .99}];
```

We now get the components of both the original image and this very sparse one comprised only of the intersection points.

```
m1 = MorphologicalComponents[im];
m2 = MorphologicalComponents[mb];
```

We can use the second one to tell us which components from `im` are of interest (that is, intersect the lines).

```
intersectedComps = 
 Union[Select[Flatten[m1*Unitize[m2]], # >= .99 &]]

(* Out[129]= {4, 5} *)
```

Now we show the image with only these components 9again, there must be a better way...)

```
Image[Map[KroneckerDelta[4 - #] + KroneckerDelta[5 - #] &, m1, {2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace the averaging step and the `MorphologicalBinarize` step with just `ImageMultiply[im2, line]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. This is my solution inspired by @BoLe:

```
m = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq6JZ.png"];
lines = {{{37.7754, 1001.}, {38.862, 0.}}, {{0., 442.679}, {832.,437.26}}};
deleted = DeleteSmallComponents[Show[m, Graphics[{White, Thick, Line /@ lines}]]];
m = ImageMultiply[m, deleted]
```

Comment: This is not a good or robust solution because you lose control with `DeleteSmallComponents`. To see what I mean, look at what result you get with this if your line was instead `lines = {{{37.7754, 1001.}, {38.862, 0.}}, {{0., 490.679}, {832., 
     490.26}}};`